# Get number of pages between two \pagerefs?

Tags: count, pageref

I'm working on a thesis in Overleaf, and am experimenting with automatically updating the pagecounts on the title page.

I want to update two numbers, the number of pages in the thesis, as well as the number of pages in appendix.

I have successfully placed a label on the last page before the first appendix, and have the following on my title page:

`Number of pages: \pageref{labelA}.`

This works, however, i can't seem to figure out how to automatically get the number of pages in appendix? I have attempted to subtract the total number of pages, with the page at label A, but i can't work it out.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: To some extent, this will depend on how you've done your page numbering.  Some setups reset the page numbering at the appendix, so you wouldn't need any subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\numtotalpage}{
     \int_eval:n {\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
}

\newcommand{\numappendixpage}{
    \int_eval:n {\getpagerefnumber{LastPage} - \getpagerefnumber{sec:appendix-1}  + 1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\par Total number of pages: \numtotalpage
\par Total number of appendix pages: \numappendixpage

\section{Some section}

\Blindtext[30]

\appendix

\section{Some section}\label{sec:appendix-1}

\Blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```